# Objective-C: NSPredicate Check Two Arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, nspredicate

Right now, I have a working app (similar to WhatsApp) where users can do a live search using an NSTextField to add users to a group chat. Using NSPredicate, I search through an array (searchableContacts) to find any available contacts on the app, and like matches are output to a UITableView, like so:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField {

[filteredArray removeAllObjects];

NSMutableArray *partPredicates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];

NSPredicate *currentPartPredicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.searchField.text];
NSPredicate *currentPartPredicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.searchField.text];

[partPredicates addObject:currentPartPredicate1];
[partPredicates addObject:currentPartPredicate2];

NSPredicate *fullPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:partPredicates];

filteredArray = [[self.searchableContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fullPredicate] mutableCopy];

[self.searchableMembers reloadData];

}
```

On the resulting tableView, users are able to select users to add to the group. Now, I have an 'addedContacts' array.

When the user goes back into the textField to search for more users to add to the group, how can I alter my NSPredicate to include available contacts (from searchableContacts) that are not already in the group (addedContacts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the code you have for building the predicate to this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.searchField.text,  self.searchField.text];
```

You can adjust that to exclude the items in `addedContacts` using this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(NOT SELF IN %@) AND (firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@)", self.addedContacts, self.searchField.text, self.searchField.text];
```